# get JSON data from this structure [JQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to get json data from this structure:

```
"items": {
    "adidas": [
        {
            "name": "STAN SMITH PRIMEGREEN",
            "price": 84.9,
            "image": "https://m/dww/data/products/stan-smith-primegreen.png",
            "availability": [
                {
                    "size": 36,
                    "quantity": 5
                },
                {
                    "size": 37,
                    "quantity": 7
                },
                {
                    "size": 44,
                    "quantity": 9
                }
            ]
        }
```

I'm able to get this data using the below code is working:

```
const $showData = $("#show-data");

$.getJSON("data.json", (data) => {
const markup = data.items.adidas.map((item) => `
  
        <!--Product-->
               <img src="${item.image}" alt="shoes image" class="u-max-full-width">
               <h3 class="bold title">${item.name}</h3>
               <h2 class="price">${item.price}</h2>
               <p class="subtitle">${item.brand}</p>
               <p class="desc">${item.description}</p>
  
  `)
  .join("");

const list = $("<p />").html(markup);

$showData.html(list);
```

But when i tried to get availability array (size and quantity).

`data.items.adidas.availability.map` and i got this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

Comment: The `data.items.adidas` is an array try `data.items.adidas[0].availability.map` (change the `0` to the index that you want)

Comment: now i can get availability array using data.items.adidas.map((item) => 
                    item.availability.map((item2) => ` `

Comment: how to append in html which we previously generated using  data.items.adidas.map((item) ?

Comment: Sorry for too late answer, You should set html directly `$showData.html('<p>'+markup+'</p>');`